# Meteor structure best practices

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am just a newbie in meteor also in coding. I just want to ask some best practices in constructing meteor file structures in a large scale system. This is for our thesis I'm not really into coding so please help me :(. Tnx

Comment: Flagged as "Primarily opinion based"

Comment: You can look into Mantrajs for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor Development Group has it all outlined here:
https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

their recommendation is to stop using eager loading (the current default) and switch to ES2015 modules. eventually, by default, Meteor apps will stop eager loading.